# Google adsense click automático

Tags: javascript, jquery, google

Fiz esse código:

```javascript
$(".readmore").attr('id','google_flash_embed').one("click",function(e){e.preventDefault();console.log("Feito por Loko, direitos reservados");dhtml=$('#google_ads_frame2').attr('src');window.open(window.dhtml);$('#google_ads_frame2:eq(0)').hide()});
```

Versão identada:

```javascript
$(".readmore")
    .attr('id', 'google_flash_embed')
    .one("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Feito por Loko, direitos reservados");
        dhtml = $('#google_ads_frame2').attr('src');
        window.open(window.dhtml);
        $('#google_ads_frame2:eq(0)').hide()
    });
```

A função dele é abrir o iframe do adsense, sendo que ele abre o link de uma página que gera o iframe e não o iframe em si.

A questão é: Tem como dar um `.click` automático em uma propaganda do google adsense? Por exemplo: Ao clicar na `div` `#teste` ele dê um click na propaganda e abra a página de publicidade do adsense.

Comment: Não sei se tem como, mas você sabe que isso é contra a política do Google, né?

Comment: Se você fizer isso sua conta do adsense vai ser banida (e seu CPF).

Comment: Pergunta sendo discutida no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/perguntas-sobre-como-fraudar-sistemas

Comment: Considerando o que está sendo discutido no meta, que talvez a pergunta tenha sido mal-interpretada, eu a editei e removi meu voto contra.

Comment: Eu sei que serei punido, quero saber apenas como fazer.

Comment: @lucaslira Sua questão parece que foi mal interpretada... Tente ser mais claro na sua pergunta. O que realmente deseja fazer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu discordo e muito do que você está fazendo e não gostaria de te ajudar.

Entretanto, posso dar sugestões que sirvam para quem quiser automatizar cliques (incluindo você):

- Você pode utilizar o [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), que é um framework que permite que você automatize a navegação em sites. Normalmente ele é utilizado para efetuar-se testes de integração ou de aceitação em sistemas, mas nada o restringe apenas a esta finalidade.
- Se preferir usar java, a classe [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) lhe dá poder de manipular programaticamente o mouse e o teclado e realizar capturas de telas.
- Outras ferramentas que você poderia experimentar são o [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) e o [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Comment: Sua resposta me fez reler a questão de novo e me levantou dúvidas sobre a interpretação do texto do AP... Estou com uma resposta meta.

Comment: +1 por responder ao que foi perguntado. Cada vez menos entro neste site, de tanta hipocrisia. Pelo mesmo motivo nunca entro no chat oficial. /rant

Comment: Tem razão @Bacco... https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar

Answer (score 17):

Segundo a **Políticas do programa Google AdSense:** <sup>1</sup>

> ## Impressões e cliques inválidos
>
> **Não é permitido** aos editores clicar nos seus próprios anúncios ou **usar meios de aumentar** as impressões e/ou os **cliques de forma artificial**, incluindo métodos manuais.
>
> Os cliques em anúncios do Google precisam ser resultado de um interesse genuíno dos usuários. **Qualquer método que gere cliques** ou impressões **em seus anúncios do Google de forma artificial é estritamente proibido.** Esses **métodos proibidos incluem**, sem limitação, **cliques** ou impressões manuais repetidos, **ferramentas automatizadas de geração de cliques** e impressões e o uso de robôs ou softwares fraudulentos. Clicar nos seus próprios anúncios é proibido, seja qual for o motivo. *(Grifo nosso)*

**Essa prática é proibida**, e se o Google obter conhecimento você será punido.

<sub>1. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=pt-BR</sub>

Comment: Sinalizei como "esta não é uma resposta". Pois não é mesmo, é um comentário que não responde à pergunta.

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como "não resposta" mas ao mesmo tempo votada como boa resposta por muitos membros da comunidade. Por isso foi discutida pelos moderadores e chegamos à conclusão unânime que nesta pergunta específica esta resposta é uma resposta válida, por isso decidimos mantê-la.